# Is it true that for a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}^e]\subset[e,\mathfrak{g}]$ for $e$ a regular nilpotent?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensonnal semisimple Lie algebra, let $e \in \mathfrak{g}$ be a regular nilpotent element ie. an element whose adjoint endomorphism is nilpotent and of maximal rank. Denote by $\mathfrak{g}^e$ the centralizer of $e$
in $\mathfrak{g}$ ie. the set of $y\in\mathfrak{g}$ such that $[e,y]=0$.
Is it true that $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}^e]\subset[e,\mathfrak{g}]$ ? I have tried on all types up to dimension 100 using GAP and the result seems to hold.

It looks like a result that could be proven elementarily using detailed analysis of the rootspace/rootsystem in each type. This approach seems tedious so I was wondering if this result was already present in the literature or if there was a one-liner using well-known results.

Comment: I think you need to explain your notation better. What are $\mathfrak{e}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^\mathfrak{e}$ here?

Comment: $e$ sounds like an element and $\mathfrak{e}$ like a subalgebra, but it is not clear what is the relation between the two

Comment: @Callum, $\mathfrak{e}$ was a spelling mistake, it should be clearer now.

Comment: I feel like you should be able to prove this by observing that the action of $e$ induces a filtration on the Lie algebra: $\mathfrak{g} \geq [e, \mathfrak{g}] \geq [e, [e, \mathfrak{g}]] \geq \cdots$ where $\mathfrak{g}^e$ is the final non-trivial subspace. You have to understand how the bracket interacts with the filtration but I think the filtration is the same as that induced by the Borel subalgebra containing $e$ and that is easy to work with.

Comment: @Callum, using the decomposition of $\mathfrak{g}$ as $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-modules induced by an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple containing $e$, it seems to me that one can make this filtration explicit and that the last non-trivial subspace will be the root-space corresponding to the highest root and not $\mathfrak{g}^e$. Am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: No you are correct , that is my mistake.

Comment: If I take $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb C)$, $e= \pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$, I get $\pmatrix{0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0} \in [\mathfrak g, \mathfrak g^e]$ but $\notin [e,\mathfrak g]$. What am I missing?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg that $e$ is nilpotent but it is not regular

Comment: I must be totally blind then, but what is a regular nilpotent in $\mathfrak{sl}_3$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ has a centraliser of dimension 4 by my count whereas $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ has one of dimension 2 which I think is the smallest possible making it regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true:

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the Killing form of $\mathfrak{g}$, using invariance of $\mathcal{K}$, one shows that $[\mathfrak{g},e]\subset{\mathfrak{g}^e}^\perp$ (orthogonality is with respect to $\mathcal{K}$). By non degeneracy of $\mathcal{K}$, the two spaces have same dimension hence they are equal. Again using invariance of $\mathcal{K}$ and knowing that $\mathfrak{g}^e$ is abelian because $e$ is regular, we conclude that $[\mathfrak{g}^e,\mathfrak{g}]\subset{\mathfrak{g}^e}^\perp=[\mathfrak{g},e]$.

Comment: How does non-degeneracy of the Killing form imply those two spaces have the same dimension?

Comment: I did not mentionned that $\mathfrak{g}$ was finite-dimensionnal. Assuming it is, by the rank theorem we have $\dim\mathfrak{g}^e$+$\dim[\mathfrak{g},e]=\dim\mathfrak{g}$ and non-degeneracy implies that $\dim V^\perp+\dim V=\dim\mathfrak{g}$ for any vector subspace $V\subset\mathfrak{g}$. Aplying it to $V=\mathfrak{g}^e$ gives the equality.

Comment: I see, nice proof. By the way, do you have a quick reference or proof for "centralizer of regular(-nilpotent) element is abelian"? It seems to be folklore, but I cannot pin it down.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, you can finda proof for the equivalence as $\textit{Theorem 35.6.8}$ in Tauvel, P., & Yu, R. W. T. (2005). Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups. In Springer Monographs in Mathematics. Springer Berlin Heidelberg. https://doi.org/10.1007/b139060 . And looking at it, the answer to the question I given is  a weaker version of $\textit{Proposition 35.3.1}$ but the proof are the same.